# PERMISSION_DENIED: Invalid permissions on the specified KeyVault - Azure Databricks & Keyvault

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

I have created KeyValut and Azure Databricks
When i am trying to test it i am getting the below error.

com.databricks.common.client.DatabricksServiceHttpClientException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Invalid permissions on the specified KeyVault https://p2keyvaultazdbricks.vault.azure.net/. Wrapped Message: Status code 403, {"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource.\r\nIf role assignments, deny assignments or role definitions were changed recently, please observe propagation time.\r\nCaller: name=AzureDatabricks;appid=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d;oid=736dc8c5-a7bd-4c1c-926a-0dc3775cf186;iss=https://sts.windows.net/8d59fa69-fece-4e80-8578-152289b590fa/\r\nAction: 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/getSecret/action'\r\nResource: '/subscriptions/1868d467-56e9-4d01-961a-1aab1f1dae92/resourcegroups/p2adfdatabrics_rg/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/p2keyvaultazdbricks/secrets/p2sastokenforstorage'\r\nAssignment: (not found)\r\nDecisionReason: 'DeniedWithNoValidRBAC' \r\nVault: p2keyvaultazdbricks;location=australiaeast\r\n","innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByRbac"}}}

Tried to get acess policies--> But its saying 'Access Policies not available'

Answer (score 0):

You cant get to 'Access policies' of AKV right? If thats the case, you may not have the necessary permissions to view or modify access policies for AKV, or simply you have RBAC model for AKV. You need to set them at IAM section, which is 3 tabs above Access Policies in the Portal UI. To access and manage access policies, you need to have the appropriate Azure RBAC role assigned at the AKV or resource group level. The role required to manage access policies is "Key Vault Contributor". You most probably have RBAC since you cannot do access policies, as this is not available for RBAC model

Questions:

1. Do you have any locks set at your AKV?
2. Is this a subscription related to your work, where your access is managed by the organization?

Note: for common errors like this you can also use 'Diagnose and solve problems' tab so that azure can search for the possible cause, the relevant troubleshooting options are available under 'Managing Access and Networking configuration'

[image]